# Arbitrary/string return value from LiteDb query

Tags: c#, litedb

I have a LiteDb database on which I would like the user to be able to run arbitrary queries (given as a string; assume that we demand their query also always returns a string). Unfortunately I seem to be locked into always receiving the type given in the collection. For example the query

```
SELECT "hello"
```

is valid SQL as far as I understand but LiteDb doesn't parse it:

```
new LiteDatabase(dbFile).GetCollection<MyType>().Find("SELECT 'hello'");
```

Gives the error

> Unexpected token `HELLO` in position 10.

Of course it's not unexpected that this example will fail, since `Find` is supposed to always return an `IEnumerable<MyType>` but I can't find a way that can run an arbitrary valid query. Is there a good way around this? I understand the LiteDb is not supposed to be an SQL server but I need the kind of flexibility to allow the user to get strings back from their logic; sort of like allowing them to program the database a bit.

Comment: You are creating one big sql injection app. What are you going to do if someone puts in a command to delete all your databases? or store specially crafted viruses, or <insert attack vector here>

Comment: @TheGeneral It's not high-security data and we delete it perennially anyway, so that's not presently a concern. How would you inject a virus through an SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Execute() method in your LiteDatabase instance. It basically returns you a collection of BsonValues:

```
var result = liteDatabase.Execute("SELECT 'John' AS Name, 34 AS Age").ToEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(x => ((Dictionary<string, BsonValue>)x.RawValue)
    .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value.RawValue.ToString()));

foreach (var r in result) Console.WriteLine($"{r.Key}: {r.Value}");
```

However, this comes with a great burden that puts you in the obligation to consider all possible forms of complexity. In this simple case you will get a KeyValuePair, but with more complex queries you have to deal with a more complex output - so I recommend you to limit yourself on just handling KeyValuePairs or comparable data structures.

Comment: Great! This looks exactly like what I'm looking for. I will mark this as answered once I've done a bunch of testing. Yes my use case will be fairly limited, that won't be a problem; I'm OK to constrain the user a fair bit.

Comment: For some reason trying to manipulate the Enumerable result was producing constant "already enumerated" exceptions. However the `Execute` was the important bit and just going `Execute(...).First()` gives me everything I want I think.

Comment: Just use the ToArray() or the ToList() methods on your result to be able to manipulate it. IEnumerable is a projection and thus readonly

Comment: I know, I was, I'm not trying to edit it. However enumerating it in any way seems to create an exception. That is, `_db.Execute(query).ToList().First()` throws an exception but `_db.Execute(query).First()` does not. It's almost like something in the LiteDb code is enumerating it twice.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to do nested queries with `Execute`? I.e. nested within the string query itself. I can't get them to work, always a syntax exception.